# Binary Search tree and Counter with Observer Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, binary-search-tree

So I have designed a binary search tree class..and on instruction of my teacher, rather than being composed of nodes, the tree is made up of other Binary Trees--it's children are created by inserting new binary trees.  We are needing to create a Counter class that is an observer of the size change of the tree and we need to count the number of 'nodes'  But I can't figure out how to notify on just every insert call...b/c if I notify on the creation of a new tree--my 'nodeCount' gets reset everytime in the the constructor...any ideas?

Here is my BST class

```
    package model;
    import java.util.*;

    public class BinaryTree extends Observable{

Strategy strategy;

int value;
BinaryTree leftChild;
BinaryTree rightChild;

int size;


BinaryTree(){
    value = -1;
    leftChild = null;
    rightChild = null;
}

public BinaryTree(int newValue){
    this.value = newValue;
}

public int getValue(){ return value;}

public Boolean isEmpty(){
    Boolean isEmpty;
    if(this == null)
        isEmpty = true;
    else
        isEmpty = false;
    return isEmpty;
}


public void insert(int newValue){
    if(value == -1){
        this.value = newValue;
        size = 1;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(new Integer(size));
        clearChanged();
    }
    else if(newValue < this.value){
            if(leftChild != null){
                leftChild.insert(newValue);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Inserted " + newValue + " to the left of " + value);
                leftChild = new BinaryTree(newValue);
                size = size + 1;
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(new Integer(size));
                clearChanged();
            }
    } else if (newValue >= this.value){
        if(rightChild != null){
            rightChild.insert(newValue);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Inserted " + newValue + " to the right of " + value);
            rightChild = new BinaryTree(newValue);
            size = size + 1;

            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(new Integer(size));
            clearChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

}

and here is my counter class

```
    package model;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Counter implements Observer{
private int size;
public Counter(){
    size = 0;
    System.out.println("Counter created: Size is " + size);
}

public void update(Observable BinaryTree, Object size){
    if(size instanceof Integer){
        size = ((Integer)size).intValue();
        System.out.println("Counter : Size changed to " + size);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Counter: Some other change to the tree");
    }
}
```

}

and here is some sample output...as soon as a new tree is created the counter goes away--I think I understand the problem I just have no idea how to fix it..I tried using a Delegated Observer but that just confused me even more..any suggestions?

```
Please enter as many integers as you'd like, hit 'Q' when you are finished.

2
Counter : Size changed to 1
4
Inserted 4 to the right of 2
Counter : Size changed to 2
3
Inserted 3 to the left of 4
5
Inserted 5 to the right of 4
4
Inserted 4 to the left of 5
5
Inserted 5 to the right of 5
```

this is the main method

```
    package model;
    import java.io.*; 
    import java.util.*; 


    public class menu {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int integerInput;
    int inputOption;

    BinaryTree myIntTree;
    myIntTree = new BinaryTree();

    Counter sizeObs = new Counter();
    myIntTree.addObserver(sizeObs);


    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    do{

    System.out.println("=======================================");
    System.out.println("     Binary Search Tree Traversal!     ");
    System.out.println("=======================================");
    System.out.println("Options:                               ");
    System.out.println("  1.  Create a new binary search tree  ");
    System.out.println("  2.  Quit                             ");
    System.out.println("=======================================");

    inputOption = KeyIn.inInt("Please select an option from the menu: ");

    switch(inputOption){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You've selected to create a new binary tree." + "\n");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            //String again;
            String tempInput;
            Boolean repeat = true;
            try{
                System.out.println("Please enter as many integers as you'd like, hit 'Q' when you are finished." + "\n");
                do{

                    tempInput = scan.next();
                    if(!tempInput.equals("Q") && !tempInput.equals("q")){
                        integerInput = Integer.parseInt(tempInput);
                        myIntTree.insert(integerInput);
                        repeat = true;
                    }
                    else
                        repeat = false;

                }while(repeat);

            }catch(InputMismatchException e){}

        break;

        case 2:

            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid selection.");
            break;              
    }
}while(inputOption != 2);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are trying to keep track of the main tree (the one originating at the main root). But you should be aware that some of the inserts are made to subtrees of the this main tree (i.e. one of the nodes belonging to the big/main tree).

You don't "observe" these nodes (subtrees). Each time you create a new node, e.g:

```
 leftChild = new BinaryTree(newValue);
```

you should also add it an observer (i.e a Counter instance).

The problem is that, this way, you will have an Observer for each of your trees and each of them will keep track of a different `size` which is the size instance variable of that tree.

You should use a class variable `size` in the `BinaryTree` class which you should update when you insert a new tree. This way all the Counters will keep track of the same size var.

Comment: I think I am confused... I added a size incrementer to the two Binary Tree constructors but I'm still losing my counter after I get to 3...am I misunderstanding what you suggested?  I thought I already had my counter paying attention to the size change ?

Comment: I said instance variable instead of class variable. Sorry. 
can you show the code where you add the observer to the observable ?

Comment: does that mean I declare size where my main is?  I did some quick googling for an example and I have managed to confuse myself...this is where my main method adds in everything

Comment: I did as you said--changed to update to after the entire insert method as opposed to updating every time a new tree was created.  Works great! Thanks!!